# Python: is there an equivalent to logging.getLogger(__name__) for argparse's parsers to pass args between modules?

Tags: python, logging, module, global, argparse

The logging library allows us to define a global logger that can be accessed from any imported modules, like so:

main_script.py:

```
import logging
import module.py

if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.config.fileConfig('/path/to/logging.conf')
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

And then in module.py:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

This is great as it means there is no need to pass around verbose or debug flags between modules.

I would have thought something equivalent would exist for argparse, allowing for example the parsing either in the main script or in a separate module, and then providing a way to access them from any other module. After all, sys.argv is accessible from any module, but it seems somewhat ridiculous to recreate a new parser in each module just to access them; and the alternative is to pass args around in functions calls.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `argparse` is relatively simple and self contained.  As you note it accesses `sys.argv`.  Otherwise it doesn't have any global embodiment or hooks.  Normally `parse_args()` is called from a `if __name__=='__main__':` block, so it is only used by the `main` script, not by imported modules.  Having several active parsers is asking for trouble.

Comment: That was also my sentiment, but I'd like to avoid ending up with args as the first argument of every function in most of my modules (which is the direction it's taking...) so I was wondering if there was an alternative considered best practice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`logging` keeps track of loggers in its module namespace. Since `logging.logger` runs in that namespace its easy for it to find the logger you want. `argparse` doesn't do that but you can implement the same functionality in your own modules. Create a module that everyone can import and have it do the argument parsing for you. The first one to call triggers the argument parsing and the others just get the result.

myconfig.py

```
import sys
import argparse

args = None

def get_args(argv=sys.argv):
    global args
    if args is None:
        parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Foo The Bar')
        # todo: add arguments…
        args = parser.parse_args(argv)
    return args
```

One likely wants to call `get_args` early in the main script processing in case there is an error or perhaps all the caller wanted was `--help`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have looked around forever, can't believe I'm the only one who had that problem. Your solution seems quite nifty and logical now that I think of it! Is it considered best practice to access args this way?

Comment: As for best practice... that's quite a subject. Here's my take - global config runs against testability. I prefer to write my programs in smaller chunks that can be tested with canned state and then pull them together in a main. Main would argparse but build smaller objects from the config for the actual program. HOWEVER (!) I've worked on very successful projects where the rich command / subcommand parsing available through argparse was a central feature. In a sense, argparse was the main. So I can argue both sides equally.